# How do I use /etc/network/interfaces instead of network-manager

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have 12.04 Desktop installed, how do I uninstall Network-Manager and set `/etc/network/interfaces` as the default file to resolve my network connections?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you manually manage your network card in `/etc/network/interfaces` , network manger will not manage it , it will state **"Not Managed"**

Suppose your network card is eth0 :

To setup eth0 to **static**, enter:

```
open /etc/network/interfaces :

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.15 #------> Your Ip Address
netmask 255.255.255.0 #------> Netmask
gateway 192.168.1.254 #-------> Gateway
broadcast 192.168.0.255 
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.3 #-----> Dns server
```

To setup eth0 to **dhcp**, enter:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The different keywords have the following meaning:

**auto**: the interface should be configured during boot time.

**iface** : interface

**inet**: interface uses TCP/IP networking.

Now restart service :

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Dont set `network` and `broadcast` in `/e/n/interfaces` if you dont need it. Of you get it right it usually doesn't matter and if you get it wrong, like you have done and it is easy to get it wrong, you could lose some network confections. The computer is better than us to calculate this. You should also check that the package `resolvconf` is installed, or the dns-directives will not work.

Answer (score 5):

In the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:0C:29:90:24:0F,00:0C:29:2E:C8:2C,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

where `false` means that network-manager doesn't manage the interfaces located in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: And that's the default, as was answered three years ago.

Comment: @muru Can we change nmcli to change configuration in /etc/network/interfaces rather than in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/