# /etc/network/interfaces is almost empty

Tags: 12.04, ltsp, static-ip

I'm trying to set up a static IP address for my LTSP server as to configure one of my two NICs (internal one : Server -> Light client) via the `/etc/network/interfaces` , but when I open the interfaces file all I can see is this :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This is normal.** What you have is exactly the same as what's in `/etc/network/interfaces` on my Ubuntu 14.04 system (which is working fine and networking actively through two separate physical interfaces).

By default an Ubuntu desktop system uses [NetworkManager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager) to manage network connections automatically and dynamically. This does not require (and in fact typically requires there *not* be) entries detailing configuration of your physical interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

(NetworkManager, if changed from running in "unnmanaged mode" to "managed mode," will recognize and work with `/etc/network/interfaces` entries. But unmanaged mode is the default.)

Sources:

- [Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) - [Network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager) - [Issues](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Issues)
- [nux's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/431693/22949) to [How do I use /etc/network/interfaces instead of network-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431682/how-do-i-use-etc-network-interfaces-instead-of-network-manager)
- [NetworkManager (on Debian wiki)](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager#NetworkManager-1)
- NetworkManager's [README.Debian file](http://wl.hopto.org/doc/network-manager/README.Debian) (also `/usr/share/doc/network-manager/README.Debian`, and [related](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1571466))
- [BatchyX's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121381/11938) to [Wireless Networks showing “device not managed” in Network Manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121356/wireless-networks-showing-device-not-managed-in-network-manager)

Comment: THank you for the response :)
So if I disable Network manager, or change it from running in "unmanaged mode" to "managed mode" I should be able to monitor my network information from the interfaces file, but at the same time still keep the functionalities of network manager?

Comment: According to what I read on the NetworkManager source (on Debian wiki) you provided, if a connexion's information are present on the interfaces file, it is not managed by Network manager, is that the case for Ubuntu 12.04 too?

Comment: @user3078046 Yes, you can change NetworkManager to managed mode and achieve this. Regarding 12.04: I believe yes. That is, I believe unmanaged mode is the default in Ubuntu 12.04 just as it is in later Ubuntu versions like 14.04. However, I don't currently have a 12.04 system on which to check this. You can check this for your system by running `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. (Or maybe it's `nm-system-settings.conf` in 12.04.) Under `[ifupdown]` is a line, either `managed=true` or `managed=false`. And changing it from `false` to `true` switches from unmanaged to managed mode.

Comment: I did a 'stop' command to disable network manager now I have to start it manually everytime I reboot :S.
I went to the NetworkManager.conf to switch [ifupdown] managed=false and turn it to managed=true.
I rebooted but it is still disabled on boot, what should I do?

Comment: @user3078046 Do you mean the `NetworkManager` *process* does not run anymore? (If you're not sure, you can check by running `ps ax | grep [N]etworkManager` when you think NetworkManager may not be running.) Or just that it doesn't manage your interface anymore? What "stop" command was run? Did you modify `/etc/network/interfaces` too? If the new issue is that the `NetworkManager` process will no longer run automatically (rather than running but not working the way you want), then you might want to post a separate question about that. (In that case, please include a link here and I'll look.)

Answer (score -2):

No, there should be a lot more info in the interfaces file. Have you tried setting the IP using ifconfig yet?

```
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth0 x.x.x.x
ifconfig eth0 netmask x.x.x.x
ifconfig eth0 broadcast x.xx.x.x
```

or you can try to edit the interfaces file with the following lines:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    netmask x.x.x.x
    gateway x.x.x.x
    broadcast x.x.x.x
```