# Reconnecting to wired connection requires reboot

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

Few days ago I had to connect to Internet through PPPoE and I used `pppoeconf`. Now I came back to dhcp. But whenever I make a new wired connection with NetworkManager it doesn't get able to connect with, like this:

[image: wired connection error]

If I try to connect through nmcli:

```
sudo nmcli connection up New\ 802-3-ethernet\ connection
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

dhclient doesn't works too.

But if I reboot my laptop with Ethernet cable plugged in it works properly (while cable doesn't plug out and in again).

My /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

So why does it would happen and what can I do to fix it?

**Kubuntu 16.04**

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431682/how-do-i-use-etc-network-interfaces-instead-of-network-manager) I got that any interface listed in /etc/network/interfaces are not managing by NetworkManager, so I just deleted `enp3s0` interface from this file and that is works.

/etc/network/interfaces looks like this now:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! If this is the solution to your problem, then, please, accept your own answer. (In order to be able to do that, you'll have to wait for a little while.) This way, your question will be marked as solved. Cheers!